# Select foreign key matching multiple criteria in a joining table (SQLITE)

Tags: sql, sqlite

Preface: this is all in a fiddle here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pMLFrz59aeL7B2jUsmTt9X/1

---

I have a table that contains items (`item #100, item #101...`) that each have various attributes (`color, type, size`). Because the set of attributes are not consistent (e.g. in the table below, `item #100` is a hat, which don't typically have a size), I created a map of the items to the attribute type and attribute value for each of the items.

| Item | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item #100 | Color | Red |
| Item #100 | Type | Hat |
| Item #101 | Color | Blue |
| Item #101 | Size | S |
| Item #101 | Type | T-Shirt |

*Snip*

However I am now struggling to retrieve items by an arbitrary set of multiple criteria — for example, I am unsure of how to select all items that have:

Attribute type `Size` with attribute value `s`

**AND**

Attribute type `Color`, attribute value `Blue`

(which, for the example, the query would return `Item #101` and `Item #103`)

I successfully retrieved the rows with selecting all of the individual criteria and then `Intersect`ing them together (e.g. select everything of size "s" intersected with select everything of color "blue"). That didn't seem like a good solution as the full set of criteria to query by will change (sometimes it will only by one attribute, sometimes it will be by multiple)

I am relatively new at all of this, but reading through sqlite's documentation about indices felt in the right neighborhood...

Comment: It appears to me that your table design may not be correct. It is important to have a clear understanding of what is an attribute and what is a value. In the example you have provided 'ITEM' 'TYPE' 'VALUE' are all attributes. Why do you have item #100 in two rows and item # 101 appearing in three rows.  This is just a guess from the info provided: your table should have attributes of item, colour, type, size.

Comment: Maybe my example didn't help me illustrate that well — sorry!

The approach was driven by a goal to be able to create JSON that includes an arbitrary set of what I'm calling "attributes" for given items (arbitrary key/value pairs that the keys may overlap from item to item). It made sense to me to keep a record mapping all of the item numbers to all of the *types* of attributes (`color`, `size`, etc), and the *values* of those attributes (`red`, `blue`, `S`, etc) — think the JSON in the fiddle illustrates.

But now the question is how to match parameters across multiple rows!

Comment: To save a click:
`{"Color":"Red","Type":"Hat"}`
`{"Color":"Blue","Size":"S","Type":"T-Shirt"}`
`{"Color":"Blue","Size":"10","Type":"Shoe"}`